# How can I mount a VHDx like Explorer does, instead of like Mount-DiskImage or VhdAttach do?

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, automation, storage

I use VHDx images to store some data. I want to:

- have full access to the mounted drive
- have the .vhdx file protected against accidental deletion
- have it mount automatically on startup, without having Explorer open a new window for it

So...

- Using Windows 10 Pro (1803) on bare metal
- Let's say my user is `User01`, a member of both `Users` and `Administrators`
- Create a VHDx in a folder like `C:\disks\disk01.vhdx`
- Set `C:\disks` permissions to:

  - "Deny, Everybody, Delete"
  - "Allow, SYSTEM, Full Access"
  - "Allow, Administrators, Full Access"
  - "Allow, User01, Full Access"
  - Inheritance: Enabled
- The file `C:\disks\disk01.vhdx` is now:

  - readable and writable by `User01`
  - when trying to Delete or Rename the file, Windows first asks for Administrator permissions and then throws a "File Access Denied" anyway

Now comes the weird part:

- If I mount the VHDx by clicking on the file in **Explorer**, it mounts it, opens a new Explorer window, and everything works **correctly**.
- However, if I go to Powershell (as `User01` with `Administrator` permissions) and **Mount-DiskImage** it (or use VhdAttach), then I can create files and read/write to files in the virtual drive, **but not rename or delete them!**

Permissions for the drives, as in drive Properties and SDDL `O:SYG:SYD:PAI(A;OICI;FA;;;AU)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;BU)`, appear to be the same in both cases. But they don't work the same. Somehow the VHDx's file permissions affect the virtual drive **only** when using Mount-DiskImage and **not** when using Explorer.

Permissions for the .vhdx file are: `O:{User01_SID}G:{User01_SID}D:AI(D;ID;DTSD;;;WD)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)`

**What does Explorer do differently?** How can I automatically mount VHDx images like Explorer does, but in an automated way without having to go through Explorer and having it open new windows for each drive on startup?

PS: Also, for path mounted images without an associated drive letter, Explorer shows an error modal dialog, which is really annoying.

**UPDATE**: Mounting the VHDx through "Computer Management -> Disk Management -> Attach VHD" works correctly, same as using Explorer. There is some difference between these two vs. whatever Mount-DiskImage and VhdAttach do.

Comment: I cannot answer the full question, but _when trying to Delete or Rename the file, Windows first asks for Administrator permissions and then throws a "File Access Denied" anyway_ to me means that User01 is in fact also a member of the `Everyone` group (because also in `Users`). For that group you have specifically denied the `Delete` permission wich is needed for renames or deletes. I suggest to put User01 in the Administrators group and remove him from the 'Users' group. Next, deny 'Delete' for group Users instead of 'Everyone'

Comment: @Theo This still lets `User01` delete the .vhdx file, while any other member of `Users` who is blocked from deleting it also gets blocked from deleting files on the mounted drive. Unless using Explorer instead of powershell to mount the drive.

Comment: Have you figured that out? I appear to have a very similar problem: when I only give SYSTEM and Administrators access to a .VHD file then `Mount-DiskImage` it, I get access denied trying to read any folders/files on the mounted drive.